# Transaction check error when installing python3-devel

Tags: python, python-3.x, yum

I am trying to `pip3 install uwsgi` with virtualenv on centos7, but it shows

```
In file included from plugins/python/pyutils.c:1:0:
    plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
```

I trying to `yum install python3-devel` and it shows

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/rpm/macros.ghc-srpm from install of redhat-rpm-config-9.1.0-88.el7.centos.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-6-8.noarch
```

I trying to `yum update' and it shows

```
Error: Package: remi-release-6.10-1.el6.remi.noarch (installed)
          Need: epel-release = 6
          Deleting: epel-release-6-8.noarch (installed)
              Epel-release = 6-8
          Updated by: epel-release-7-11.noarch (epel)
              Epel-release = 7-11
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

and `--skip-broken` didn't solve anything

any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you use **epel-release-6.8** on centos7. Normally you should install **epel-release-7.*** .

On my centos7 machine I have **epel-release-7.11** installed which does not contain the `/etc/rpm/macros.ghc-srpm` file. So I would recommend upgrading **epel-release**...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
This happens when I add epel repo to 32bit CentOS7.
Because there is no 32bit epel since CentOS7, I had to add 32bit epel for CentOS6 to my CentOS7.
I got python3.6 now, but can not get python3-devel through yum.
Maybe you can get it after disabling other repos?